# How can I access a File in a Repo that is located inside a folder

Tags: gitlab

This might seem trivial to most of you, but Im facing an issue where I'm confused on how can I access a file saved inside a folder inside a Repo,

I already read the documentation on GitLab API
GET /projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path
However, this is working if the file is saved not in the nested folder
Assuming I have a project called 12345 and then there is a folder called MyFiles then inside this Folder this is File01.txt
How exactly can I get to read the File01.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to url encode the `file_path`. `/` would become `%2F` and `.` would become `%2E`.

The URL would be `/projects/12345/repository/files/MyFiles%2FFile01%2Etxt`